# How can i get selected date from calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make reservation system for test with HTML, CSS, JS. I have dynamic calendar and when i select a day i need to get `"2022-03-04"` i need to choose only one date.
here is my code

```
const currentDate = document.querySelector(".current-date"),
    daysTag = document.querySelector(".days"),
    prevNextIcon = document.querySelectorAll("header img");

let date = new Date(),
    currYear = date.getFullYear(),
    currMonth = date.getMonth();

const months = ["January", "Februay", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

const renderCalendar = () => {
    let firstDayofMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 1).getDay(),
        lastDateofMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth + 1, 0).getDate(),
        lastDayofMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, lastDateofMonth).getDay(),
        lastDateofLastMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 0).getDate();
    let liTag = "";

    for (let i = firstDayofMonth; i > 0; i--) {
        liTag += `<li class="inactive">${lastDateofLastMonth - i + 1}</li>`;

    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= lastDateofMonth; i++) {

        let isToday = i === date.getDate() && currMonth === new Date().getMonth() && currYear === new Date().getFullYear() ? "active" : "";
        let isTomorrow = i - 1 === date.getDate() && currMonth === new Date().getMonth() && currYear === new Date().getFullYear() ? "active" : "";
        let isNext = i - 2 === date.getDate() && currMonth === new Date().getMonth() && currYear === new Date().getFullYear() ? "active" : "";
        liTag += `<li  class="${isToday} ${isTomorrow} ${isNext}">${i}</li>`;

    }
    

    for (let i = lastDayofMonth; i < 6; i++) {
        liTag += `<li class="inactive">${i - lastDayofMonth + 1}</li>`;
    }


    currentDate.innerText = `${months[currMonth]} ${currYear}`;
    daysTag.innerHTML = liTag;
}
renderCalendar();




prevNextIcon.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        currMonth = icon.id === "prev" ? currMonth - 1 : currMonth + 1;
        if (currMonth < 0 || currMonth > 11) {
            date = new Date(currYear, currMonth);
            currYear = date.getFullYear();
            currMonth = date.getMonth();
        } else {
            date = new Date();
        }
        renderCalendar();
    });
});
```

i used for, but it not working, i get only day. but i need

its not working, im getting only day.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a small logical error in the prevNextIcon event listeners. The check for whether currMonth is below 0 or above 11 should be done before updating currMonth, not after.

```
prevNextIcon.forEach(icon => {
icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const newMonth = icon.id === "prev" ? currMonth - 1 
                        : currMonth + 1;
    
    if (newMonth < 0) {
        currYear -= 1;
        currMonth = 11;
    } else if (newMonth > 11) {
        currYear += 1;
        currMonth = 0;
    } else {
        currMonth = newMonth;
    }
    
    renderCalendar();
});
});
```

Please try this if this can help you.